# Why pyspark give the wrong value of variance?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a registered table in pyspark.

```
+--------+-------+--------+------------+---------+-----------------+----------------------+
|order_id|user_id|eval_set|order_number|order_dow|order_hour_of_day|days_since_prior_order|
+--------+-------+--------+------------+---------+-----------------+----------------------+
| 2168274|      2|   prior|           1|        2|               11|                  null|
| 1501582|      2|   prior|           2|        5|               10|                    10|
| 1901567|      2|   prior|           3|        1|               10|                     3|
|  738281|      2|   prior|           4|        2|               10|                     8|
| 1673511|      2|   prior|           5|        3|               11|                     8|
| 1199898|      2|   prior|           6|        2|                9|                    13|
| 3194192|      2|   prior|           7|        2|               12|                    14|
|  788338|      2|   prior|           8|        1|               15|                    27|
| 1718559|      2|   prior|           9|        2|                9|                     8|
| 1447487|      2|   prior|          10|        1|               11|                     6|
| 1402090|      2|   prior|          11|        1|               10|                    30|
| 3186735|      2|   prior|          12|        1|                9|                    28|
| 3268552|      2|   prior|          13|        4|               11|                    30|
|  839880|      2|   prior|          14|        3|               10|                    13|
| 1492625|      2|   train|          15|        1|               11|                    30|
+--------+-------+--------+------------+---------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

I want to calculate the variance of `days_since_prior_order`, excluding the null value. The right value should be 97.91836734693878, which is given by hive and python. But my pyspark give me 105.45054945054943.

```
spark.sql("select variance(days_since_prior_order) from \
(select * from orders where user_id=2 and days_since_prior_order is not null ) ").show()
```

The original table data types are correct.

```
 |-- order_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- eval_set: string (nullable = true)
 |-- order_number: short (nullable = true)
 |-- order_dow: short (nullable = true)
 |-- order_hour_of_day: short (nullable = true)
 |-- days_since_prior_order: short (nullable = true)
```

Comment: How are you calculating the variance in spark, can you please provide the code. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following function instead of *pyspark.sql.functions.variance(col)*:

> pyspark.sql.functions.var_pop(col)
>
> Aggregate function: returns the population variance of the values in a group.

With your column data, var_pop gives me this result:

```
[Row(var_pop(days_since_prior_order)=97.91836734693877)]
```

The reason is that:

- **variance()** and **var_samp()** are scaled by 1/(N-1)
- **var_pop()** is scaled by 1/N

with N number of values selected.

See [population and sample variance](http://www.macroption.com/population-sample-variance-standard-deviation/) for a useful link.

[Here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.var_pop) you will find the docs of **var_pop()**